# Has anyone used LBFGS Optimizer in Tensorflow 2.0 ? How to use tfp.lbfgs_minimize inside a standard sequential training network?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

I have been building a simple sequential network in Keras. So far I used Adam optimizer for fine-tuning the results. Now I need LBFGS Optimizer in the training to improve the loss.

It seems like the examples provided in the official documentation for `tfp.lbgs_minimize` are not enough, What do I need to do to train the network effectively using the LBFGS optimizer?

Here is the simple network model I use to train on 1D data,

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Define the model architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu', input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))


# Compile the model
model.compile(loss=custom_loss,
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32)

# Evaluate the model
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print('Test loss:', loss)
print('Test accuracy:', accuracy)
```

I do have acustom loss function that's just a combination of MSE and other variables.

All help is appreciated, Thanks.